# Find the solution of the ODE $x^{\prime}+\frac{e^{t}}{t}x=\frac{2}{t^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

> Find the solution of the ODE $x^{\prime}+\frac{e^{t}}{t}x=\frac{2}{t^2}$

Consider the ODE given by $$x^{\prime}+\frac{e^{t}}{t}x=\frac{2}{t^2}$$ we should solve for a function $x$.

Consider the factor $\mu(t)=e^{\int \frac{e^t}{t} dt}$.

Notice that $\int \frac{e^t}{t}=Ei(x)$ is not elementary function (*no have a closed form*).

We multiply it by $\mu(t)$ in both sides.

$$x^{\prime} \mu(t)+\frac{e^t}{t}\mu (t)x=\frac{2}{t^2}\mu (t)$$
$$ \frac{d}{dt}[x \mu (t)]=\frac{2}{t^2}\mu (t)$$
$$ x \mu (t)=\int{\frac{2}{t^2}\mu(t)}$$

By definition of $\mu (t)$
$$\boxed{x=2e^{-\int{\frac{e^t}{t}}} \int{\frac{1}{t^2}e^{\int \frac{e^t}{t}}}+C}$$
is the general solution of the ODE.

I´m right or forguet some detail

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will edit it,now  you have suggestion for do ithe  post more clear?

Comment: Sorry, it´s a Typo, Thanks a lot again

Comment: Other than the extra 2 this is basically right, although in actuality there are more constants of integration in this expression than there should be. It is more precise to do all the integrals from the same time $t_0$ so that $x=2e^{-\int_{t_0}^t e^s/s ds} \int_{t_0}^t \frac{2}{s^2} e^{\int_{t_0}^s e^u/u du} ds$. Also, that is the particular solution satisfying $x(t_0)=0$. A small modification is needed to get the general solution.

Comment: Right, I try it

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot I appreciate your comment

Comment: ...I copied the extra 2 in my previous comment, my bad.